# is declare statement needed for arrays in bash

Tags: bash

Quick question. Is the declare statement needed when creating arrays in bash? For example I have:

```
declare -a keys
keys=( $(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_env" | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId') )
```

Or can I just create the array with this line?

```
keys=( $(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_env" | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId') )
```

Comment: Not needed for regular arrays (unless you want to set some other attributes of course). For associative arrays though, it is needed.

Comment: But if you want to make your variable local you also use declare.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga You can do `local arr; arr=(1 2 3)` without ever declaring as an array with `-a`, if you want.

Comment: You could consider all variables to be wannabe arrays:  `x=42; x[1]=37; echo "${x[@]}"` or even `y=42; y+=(37); echo "${y[@]}"`